# How to add drop down for cities at checkout page?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer-address, drop-downs

I am working on [Depoto](https://www.depoto.com)

At checkout page, I want to add city as dropdown.

Comment: please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509307/magento-configure-city-as-dropdown-option-shipping-billing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="city" placeholder="Enter City Name" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```